# Android: Filter out an application

Tags: android, filter, out

I am struggling with a weird problem. I have an application manifest that defines intent filters for office files, .doc, .ppt, etc. So, the user can go to an office file in a file explorer, choose open, and select my application. My application is not really a document viewer; it allows a user to extract images from a file.

Now, inside my application, I want to allow the user to view the selected office file in a document viewer. For this, I am providing an open button, which fires an ACTION_VIEW intent. When the activity chooser comes up, it displays my application also as an option because I have declared the intent filters in my manifest. In a nut shell, I do not want my application to be one of the options when my application sends the ACTION_VIEW intent.

Is there a way I can filter out my application from this chooser dialog?

Thanks,

Akshay

P.S: I cannot register for the SEND filter instead of the VIEW filter in my manifest due to my requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked this question on Android Developers and found that no easy solution exists. Fore more details, see http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/9e9b1007ec7ad935.

-Akshay